# AJAX on Internet Explorer: Setting innerHTML to xmlhttp.responseText fails

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

`document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;` //fails on IE: "Unknown runtime error". Line & character index is for the start of the word document. Works in Firefox.

`document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="Something special";` //works

`alert(xmlhttp.responseText)`; // works on IE (done as a debug test)

Target of "livesearch" is a `<div id="livesearch></div>` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content you're trying to insert has to be complete html in the strictest sense. One example I saw was: trying to insert `<tr><td>data</td></tr>` gives that same runtime error because without `<table>` actually in the code you're inserting, IE drops the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags, and you're trying to insert untagged text.

here was that example (user froufrou had posted this elsewhere): http://www.ericvasilik.com/2006/07/code-karma.html

Comment: Thanks for that article... it got me looking in the right direction. I haven't full solved it yet, but the issue is in the content of what I'm inserting.

Answer (score 0):

don`t insert HTML code under non-block element.

```
<p>
<div id="livesearch></div>
</p>

<a href="xxx">
<div id="livesearch></div>
</a>
```

you should:

```
<div id="xxxxx">
<div id="livesearch></div>
</div>
```